# Java program that accepts int values until the user enters a zero, and then finds the minimum positive integer

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

How do I make sure that 0 is not included as the minimum? I have made sure that the answer is not a negative number, but now I do not know how to exclude 0 as the input when it is pressed in order to find the minimum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q2
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    int input=kb.nextInt();
    int smallestValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    boolean negative=false;
    do{
        input=kb.nextInt();
        if(!negative){
           smallestValue=input;
           negative=false;
        }
        if (input<smallestValue){
           smallestValue=input;
        }
    }
    while(input!=0);
    System.out.println(smallestValue+">0");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using while loop instead of dowhile loop

```
System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
int input=kb.nextInt();
int smallestValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

while(input!=0){//loop until user inputs 0
    if(input>0) {//check for inputs greater than 0 and ignore -ve values
        if(input<smallestValue) // save the smallest value
            smallestValue = input;
    }
    input=kb.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(smallestValue+">0");
```

Comment: Thank you, Aditya

Answer (score 0):

Test that it isn't `0` **and** is less than `smallestValue`. Change

```
if (input<smallestValue){
```

to

```
if (input != 0 && input<smallestValue){
```

but, the rest of your algorithm appears to be a little flawed. I think you wanted,

```
// if(!negative){
//    smallestValue=input;
//    negative=false;
// }
if (input > 0) {
   smallestValue = Math.min(smallestValue, input);
}
```

You also currently discard the first value. A full working example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int input;
    do {
        input = kb.nextInt();
        if (input > 0) {
            smallestValue = Math.min(input, smallestValue);
        }
    } while (input != 0);
    System.out.println(smallestValue + " > 0");
}
```

You *could* also write the inner `if` as

```
if (input > 0 && input < smallestValue) {
    smallestValue = input;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately. I've tried that already and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Do-While loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = kb.nextInt();
        int smallestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        do {
            if (input < smallestValue)
                smallestValue = input;
            input = kb.nextInt();
        } while (input != 0);
        System.out.println(smallestValue + ">0");
    }

}
```